# I want autofill edit text control when a button is clicked.Here is my code.This is android app

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

My Layout Page is :

Here is my Lay out page.I want the latitude and longitude values to be printed in edit text control when the button is clicked.My Acitivity method has getLocation method and I'm using Location services API.I don't see any error during debug and also while running the app on my Tab.

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:actionBarNavMode="list">
    <TextView
        android:text="Well Name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/WellNameLabel"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/WellText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layoutDirection="inherit"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff" 
        android:hint="Well Name"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Address"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/Address" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/EditAddress" 
        android:hint="Address"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="City"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/CityL" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/CityText"
        android:hint="State"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="State"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/StateLable" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/StateText"
        android:hint="State"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Zip:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/Zip" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/ZipText"
        android:hint="Zip"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Country:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/CountryLabel" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/TextCountry"
        android:hint="Country"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Latitude"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/LatitudeLabel" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/TextLatitude"
        android:autoText="true" 
        android:hint="Latitude"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Longitude"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/LongitudeLabel" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/TextLongitude"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:hint="Longitude"
        android:editable="true" />
    <Button
        android:text="GetLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/GetLocation" />
</LinearLayout>`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:actionBarNavMode="list">
    <TextView
        android:text="Well Name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/WellNameLabel"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/WellText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layoutDirection="inherit"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff" 
        android:hint="Well Name"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Address"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/Address" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/EditAddress" 
        android:hint="Address"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="City"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/CityL" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/CityText"
        android:hint="State"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="State"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/StateLable" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/StateText"
        android:hint="State"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Zip:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/Zip" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/ZipText"
        android:hint="Zip"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Country:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/CountryLabel" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/TextCountry"
        android:hint="Country"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Latitude"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/LatitudeLabel" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/TextLatitude"
        android:autoText="true" 
        android:hint="Latitude"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Longitude"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:id="@+id/LongitudeLabel" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff"
        android:id="@+id/TextLongitude"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:hint="Longitude"
        android:editable="true" />
    <Button
        android:text="GetLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/GetLocation" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

My Acitvity Page is as follows:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Android.Locations;

    namespace HydrologyHeck
    {
    [Activity(Label = "WellInfo")]
    public class WellInfo : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.WellReadings);
            // Create your application here
        }
        public void GetLocation(Location location)
        {
            var Latitude = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.TextLatitude);
            Latitude.Text = location.Latitude.ToString();
            var Longitude = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.TextLongitude);
            Longitude.Text = location.Longitude.ToString();
            //var geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            //var Address = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Address);
            //Address.Text = geocoder.GetFromLocation(location.Latitude, location.Longitude, 1).ToString();
            //Toast.MakeText(this,"The address is"+ Address.Text, ToastLength.Short).Show();

        }
    }
}
```

Thank You all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the Ilocation Listener on your Activity and change the EditText value on the OnLocationChanged Event, check here for more details https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/location/

You can use this example code also:

```
LocationManager locMgr;
    string tag = "MainActivity";

    public override void OnStart ()
    {
        base.OnStart ();
        Log.Debug (tag, "OnStart called");
    }
    public override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume (); 
        Log.Debug (tag, "OnResume called");

        // initialize location manager
        locMgr = Activity.GetSystemService (Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;

        string Provider = LocationManager.GpsProvider;

        //if (locationProvider != null) {
        if (locMgr.IsProviderEnabled(Provider)) {
            locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates (Provider, 2000, 1, this);
        } else {
            Log.Info (tag, "No location providers available");              
        }
    }

    public override void OnPause ()
    {
        base.OnPause ();

        // RemoveUpdates takes a pending intent - here, we pass the current Activity
        locMgr.RemoveUpdates (this);
        Log.Debug (tag, "Location updates paused because application is entering the background");
    }
    public override void OnStop ()
    {
        base.OnStop ();
        Log.Debug (tag, "OnStop called");
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged (Android.Locations.Location location)
    {
        Log.Debug (tag, "Location changed");

        var currentCoordinates = new Coordinates (location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
        LoadData (currentCoordinates);
        Latitude.Text = "Latitude: " + location.Latitude.ToString();
        Longitude.Text  = "Longitude: " + location.Longitude.ToString();
    }
    public void OnProviderDisabled (string provider)
    {
        Log.Debug (tag, provider + " disabled by user");
    }
    public void OnProviderEnabled (string provider)
    {
        Log.Debug (tag, provider + " enabled by user");
    }
    public void OnStatusChanged (string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.Debug (tag, provider + " availability has changed to " + status.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I tried to write the code.        locMgr = Activity.GetSystemService (Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
I'm getting this "Error 5 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Android.Content.Context.GetSystemService(string)'

Comment: my code example is for fragments, in your case you should use locMgr = GetSystemService (Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;